# How to make Tab insert a set number of Spaces in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, tabs

I want to not use tabs in emacs, I would like to set it so that pressing the tab key inserts a set number of spaces based on the file type. For example, I would like pressing tab to insert 4 spaces when working on a python file. Here is my current .emacs file

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))
```

Currently, whenever I press tab, it only adds any spaces if it is what emacs deems a proper spot. For example, if i opened a python file and pressed tab, nothing would happen. However, if i typed "if:" and then hit tab on the next line, it would add 4 spaces. However, if i pressed tab again, it takes me back to the beginning of the line. I think I would just like to make it so that it adds a set number of spaces, plain and simple(unless someone can give me a good reason for why it's useful to have tab cycle through the line).

The main reason I want this is because I am working on a project where the commenting following a specific format involving the use of indentation based on sets of 4 spaces. 
For example:

```
    r"""
    Return the value of the q-gamma function. 

    .. MATH::

        qgamma(z,q) = \Gamma_q (z).
    """
```

So, for the line with "qgamma", I have to start it with 8 spaces, and I would like to be able to od that by pressing tab twice. However, emacs doesn't think this is a proper place to be able to tab twice, so whenever I press tab twice, it takes me back to the beginning of the line.

Thanks!

Edit: checking the major mode variable says that it is on python-mode.

Comment: You may want to add which major mode you are using for editing Python files.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x customize`, search for `py-tab-indent`, toggle it off and `Apply`.  I believe that's the behavior that you're looking for.  Test it out and if so, `Apply and Save` the customization.

Noting, as @jpkotta pointed out, that the above is for `python-mode.el`, not the built-in `python.el`.

Comment: This is for `python-mode.el`, which is not the same as the built in `python.el`.

Comment: Sorry, he had mentioned python-mode. I was thinking he was referring to the python-mode package.

Comment: It's still ambiguous.  The major mode is `python-mode` for both.  I wasn't pointing out that your answer is somehow bad, just that you should note which python mode you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built in `python.el`, you can set `indent-line-function` to `indent-relative` instead of `python-indent-line-function` in `python-mode-hook`.

```
(defun jpk/python-mode-hook ()
  (setq indent-line-function #'indent-relative))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'jpk/python-mode-hook)
```

---

Each major mode has its own indentation function, pointed to by the `indent-line-function` variable.  `indent-relative` is a very basic, generic indentation function, and is used for `fundamental-mode` (the most basic major mode).

---

Python is a bit weird in Emacs in that it has two widely used major modes, the built in `python.el` and third-party `python-mode.el`.  Use whichever you want, but be aware of which you're using and which people are referring to in articles and SO answers.